# Close video player on IOS when ended with html, javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ios

i am using html,js to create a tag . When i play video on browser of Android Device, open full screen to watch. After video end, it will be close because i used JS on this. But with IOS, i watched with safari, it not close when ended of video, it just stop and doesnt close video player. After researched, i know different between ios player and another device.

HTML Code :

```
<video id="my-video" class="video-js"></video>
```

JS Code :

```
player.on('ended', function () {
        alert("closed ios player")
    }
```

Some body help me : How to close ios player when end video with html and js [IOS Player](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HZFY.jpg)

Im trying to find another help me close ios player when ended video with HTML JS

Comment: You'll have to post your code or no one will be able to help you. (But it will have to be someone else. Debugging cross-browser quirks is always time-consuming, and I don't own any Apple devices.)

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't closing the video player. Fix:

```
player.on( 'ended', function () {
    if( Document.exitFullscreen ) Document.exitFullscreen();
    if( Document.webkitExitFullscreen ) Document.webkitExitFullscreen();
} );
```

Comment: Hello @Michael, i have stupid question but. What is webkitExitFullscreen? I doesnt find it, and when i researched it on google its API

Comment: It's just Document.exitFullscreen(), but with Apple's vendor-specific prefix. Exiting full screen was a feature added in Safari 12, but only with the "webkit" prefix, and only on iPad, not iPhone. Modern versions of Safari might be different, but Apple has terrible documentation, so good luck.